# Simplify selector with numbered IDs

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

I have a series of divs on the same page for which I have attached a click function that acts like an `<a>` tag, directing the user to a URL extracted from a custom data-attribute. My HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="my-button1" class="button-style-1" data-href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
  Button
</div>

<div id="my-button2" class="button-style-1" data-href="http://www.w3schools.com">
  Button 2
</div>
```

and jQuery:

```
$('#my-button1,#my-button2').click(function() {
    var dataURL = $(this).data('href');
    window.open(dataURL, '_blank');
  });
```

My question is this, is it possible to simplify the selector to something like:

```
$('#my-button[i]')
```

such that it would be much more compact in the event that I have many of these divs contained on the same page? If it is possible, how would I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `$('div[data-href]')` which will apply to any div with a `data-href` attribute.

Your example with an update: https://jsfiddle.net/fLj7y0kz/1/

The typical way I've done it and seen it done is as @arop suggests and use a specific class for those elements and use the class selector `$('div.myclass`)`.

Comment: Perfect! I will accept this answer when I can, and I will upvote when I have the reputation.

Answer (score 3):

why not use a class on every button? then just select the class

```
$('.my-buttons').click(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth-child() property to get the element by index. Look at the below example code
            $('#my-button:nth-child (1)').click (function (){})

Answer (score 0):

Created dynamic divs with ids from the loop.Hope this is helpful for you

```
var mybutton = [];
var url = ["http://www.stackoverflow.com", 
           "http://www.w3schools.com",
           "http://www.w3schools.com/jquery", 
            "http://www.w3schools.com/css"];

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  //alert("hi");
  $("body").append("<div class='button-style-1' 
     id='mybutton[" + [i] +"]' data-href=" + url[i] + ">Button</div>")

}
```

codepen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/xOVERN

Comment: on click of button of those created button divs was achieved by using class-".button-style-1"